# Why background-image doesn't work in IE9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This is the website:

http://loveloverun.com/test/love_run/

I checked and it works properly in chrome and firefox. The problem is that in IE9 the background image only works on the body level.

Here is my css:

```
body {
    font-family : Open Sans;
    min-height: 0px;
    background: url("../img/front/bg.png") repeat;
    height:auto;
}
```

And the other div e.g. container

```
.container {
    width: 1022px !important; /*1302px*/
    background-color:#ffffff;
    background-clip:content-box;
}
```

and one more example (footer):

```
#enquiry {
    color:#ffffff;
    background: url("../img/front/black.png") repeat; 
}
```

I checked the doc type and it's not missing any tag.

And also some other places are different from the chrome / firefox one, so I wonder:

1) Are there any plugin to enhance the compatibility? I tried modernizer, but it seems to have no effect.

2) How can background problem be solved for IE9?

**Update:**

```
body {
    font-family : Open Sans;
    min-height: 0px;
    background-image: url("../img/front/bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height:auto;
}
```

still the same result

**Update 2:**

Screen cap in ie9

[image]

Comment: this is definitely not a javascript nor a jquery question.

Comment: removed. Thanks for remain

Comment: It should work in IE9 the way you have it. What's the relevant HTML code?  Perhaps #enquiry box dimensions are simply too small for your background to be visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
background-image: url(/image.whatever);
```

instead of the

```
background: url (); code
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the error. it still the same..any idea?

Comment: In many cases, the "background-image: url();" always seems to work, and also worked when I tried it with my own personal website. 
Have you tried running it with that already?

Comment: Just checked IE7,8 and 9, your footer background shows up as expected in all versions. Clear you cache maybe?

Comment: On your sources, I noticed that you have a background gradient set to be used if the browser is detected to be IE9 ... Can you take that off your HTML document, and try running it then with the background-image code and see if it runs then.

Comment: yes, just updated, seems nothing changed, would you mind to take a look at the site?

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't even display background-color:#ffffff where your sponsors image is. And background-color should work for sure. Clear all your cache! Wipe out IE temporary files.  Internet Options > General: Browsing History > Delete

Comment: Your website seems to be working perfectly fine with the background and everything on IE 10 and up. But for some reason it just doesn't work on IE9.

Comment: Can you try removing the dots from "../img/front/bg.png" and see if that helps. That might be confusing the browser; instead, type in the full directory name.

Comment: thanks. I find out the reason, it is caused by the theme... who claimed work on IE9 but many comment has replied that it does not... http://themeforest.net/item/admindesigns-bootstrap-admin-template-framework/9903221

Comment: Well, i doubt any heavy users use Internet explorer, and some of which do, actually always update their browsers, so you shouldn't really worry about that.